# Applying function to partial's property in Doctrine Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a following query which select a partial object and then applying ABS function to one of its property. I got the result but i have errors in rendering in twig template. Like so:

```
public function findAll($params = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('coa')
    -->select('PARTIAL coa.{id, accountCode, description, normal, createdAt}', 'ABS(coa.accountCode) as abs', 'at')
    ->join('coa.accountType', 'at');

    if (!empty($params)) {
        if (!empty($params['accountCode'])) {
            $qb->andWhere("REGEXP(:accountCode, coa.accountCode) = 1")
            ->setParameter('accountCode', '[[:<:]](' . preg_quote($params['accountCode']) . ')');
        }

        if (!empty($params['description'])) {
            $qb->andWhere("REGEXP(:description, coa.description) = 1")
            ->setParameter('description', '[[:<:]](' . preg_quote($params['description']) . ')');
        }

        if (!empty($params['normal'])) {
            $qb->andWhere('coa.normal = :normal')
            ->setParameter('normal', $params['normal']);
        }

        if (!empty($params['accountType'])) {
            $qb->andWhere('at.id = :accountTypeId')
            ->setParameter('accountTypeId', $params['accountType']->getId());
        }

        if (!is_null($params['status'])) {
            $qb->andWhere('coa.active = :status')
            ->setParameter('status', $params['status']);
        }
    } else {
        $qb->andWhere('coa.active = 1');
    }

    //$qb->orderBy('ABS(coa.accountCode)', 'ASC');

    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

I got the error in my twig saying:

> Key "id" for array with keys "0, abs" does not exist in CIAccountingBundle:ChartOfAccounts:indexContent.html.twig at line 28

This is the line 28:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('chartofaccounts_show', { 'id' : entity.id }) }}">{{ FAIcon('search-plus') }} View</a></li>
```

What do the error mean? I think i got error on select and I cant figure out the right way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are selecting 2 things :

- The partial object
- The abs

For each entity, you become an array :
- Key 0 : entity
- Key abs: abs

In your twig template replace entity.id with entity[0].id and it should work.